# Gravitational potential energy between a black hole and a mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, potential-energy

Let's think that there is a black hole with mass $M$ and matter with mass $m$. Two objects have distance $R$. What is the gravitational potential energy between the black hole and the mass? How can I obtain the value?
For the convenience of calculation, few suggestions are followed.

1. The black hole is a Schwarzschild black hole.
2. You can use any coordinates you want.

Comment: I suppose you are forcing us to use General Relativity, because the Newtonian approximation would be too easy (GMm/r). Correct?

Comment: How far apart are the two masses? In other words, what's the ratio of $\text{separation}/\text{Schwarzschild radius}$?

Comment: If you define the potential energy as the total energy minus the kinetic energy minus the rest energy you can use the definition at http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=554#p554 anyway this is one way how you can solve for the escape velocity, so set the kinetic energy equal to the negative potential energy, then your particle can escape to infinity

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a General Relativity answer, I have bad news. From the [Wikipedia article on Gravitational Potential Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy?wprov=sfla1), in the GR section:

> In general relativity gravitational energy is extremely complex, and there is no single agreed upon definition of the concept.

amd your question would be opinion-based and non-mainstream. If you're looking for an approximate Newtonian answer, then it's

$U(R) =-G\frac{Mm}{r} $

Comment: The Wiki quote applies to dynamic spacetimes. In the static Schwarzschild spacetime, the potential energy is defined perfectly well.

Comment: If this is the case, then I don't know the answer: in all my GR classes, the professors always told us to be aware that anything "potential energy" in GR is a not well defined subject. Care to show the correct answer?